# Why eventlistener click requires a return function to work

Tags: javascript

//This works

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Button ' + i));
    btn.addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
        return function() {console.log(i)};
    })(i));
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

//This doesn't work

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Button ' + i));
    btn.addEventListener('click', (function(i) {
        return console.log(i);
    })(i));
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sjzLhur0/

Could someone tell me why the second example doesn't work? Why would you need to return a function?

Comment: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Why are you passing an immediately executing function that returns another function as the second argument? Why don't you just write `btn.addEventListener('click',function(i){console.log(i)});`?

Comment: It's an interview question http://www.toptal.com/javascript/interview-questions I'm just trying to understand it. Also, just adding console.log will not return the index. Try it out in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using an IIFE, we can substitute it with its return value. So the first example is similar to

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {console.log(i)});
```

and the second example is similar to

```
 btn.addEventListener('click', console.log(i));
```

(the actual value of `i` is irrelevant to the problem at hand)

`addEventListener` expects a function to be passed as second argument but the second example doesn't pass one. It passes the return value of `console.log`, which is `undefined`. So there is nothing to executed on click.

> Why eventlistener click requires a return function to work

Note that the event listener doesn't return a function. In your first example, `function() {console.log(i)}` is the event handler. The outer function `(function(i) { ... }(i))` is just a function that *generates* the event handler.

Comment: Thank you, my objective is to just understand the example and their solution you'll find on this site. http://www.toptal.com/javascript/interview-questions

Comment: I also notice if you pass console into addEventListener, the click event doesn't seem to output anything to the console.

Comment: `console` is not a function. `addEventListener` expects a function.

Comment: Okay, sorry I miss interpreted  your example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So in the essence you are subscribing to an event which is going to happen somewhere in the future (once you click the button).

In the first (working) example, when you create an IIFE and the result of IIFE is an function then when event happens there is a callback (returned function) which is called to generate the desired result.

In the second (non-working) example you are creating an IIFE which is executed immediately so you get something as:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', undefined);
```

As the second parameter is not a function (as required) there's nothing to execute once you press the button and callback is fired.

Answer (score 0):

Because the first example is not really returning a function. There is nowhere for your function to return anything to, so is can't return anything. In your first example, it is returning a function, but that function is really just calling `console.log(i);`. Your second example would work if you said `console.log(i);` as opposed to `return console.log(i);`

Comment: Second example doesn't work removing the return. I guess It's still not clear why a function much be returned.

Comment: A function must be returned because that's what the method requires: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener. Run this in your web inspector console and see what you get: `typeof console.log('hello world')` (will return 'undefined'). Then try `typeof function(){console.log('hello world');}` (will return 'function').

Comment: You say "the first example is not really returning a function"  and "In your first example, it is returning a function". Aren't you contradicting yourself?